# file not found from sharepoint 2010 to 2013 migration

Tags: migration

I am migrating my application from SharePoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013.

I have taken the backup of my 2010 site and then created the 2013 application in classic mode authentication.

Then I have deployed the solution from visual studio all the things are working except small changes.

until this all things were ok!!

But when I applied this changes in the qal server instead of deploying the changes from the visual studio i deployed the changes from the power shell command.After this when I tried to access the changes I was getting the error of the page not found for the application changes.

when I google this problem I found that my site is accesing the old layout page of 14 hive and for that I made the chagnes in the content database SPUIversion from the table ALLDocs.

according to this link http://sadomovalex.blogspot.in/2012/10/problems-with-upgrading-claims-based.html

then changes were working fine.

Now my admin team is not allowing me to make changes in the content database.

I searched but I didnt get any solution for this problem

Guys please help me  out

Thanks and Regards,

Swapnil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploy the solution in compatibility mode and it will work fine, below is the command:

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp -GACDeployment -CompatibilityLevel {14,15}
```

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534.aspx)

Also you can perform UserRole migration, it also helps, you check out this [msdn link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx).

Comment: We have done this before not worked I redeployed the changes and its working correctly now